# Estimating the decay parameter in Exponentially Weighted Moving Average (EWMA) model

Tags: estimation, nonlinear-regression, moving-average, exponential-smoothing

Given the data $y_t$, $t=1, \cdots ,N$; I would like to estimate the decay parameter $\lambda$ in Exponentially Weighted Moving Average (EWMA) model, such that

$y_{t+1} = \sum_{k=0}^K \lambda^k y_{t - k} + e_t $,
where $K<N$.

I am wondering, is there any common way and solver for this nonlinear least squares problem? Is it possible to make this problem more "friendly" by changing of the variables?

Comment: Please do not cross post at Quantitative Finance SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi: The non geometric series version of the ES model is

$\tilde y_t = \lambda \tilde{y}_{t-1} + (1-\lambda) y_{t-1}$. ( you left out the multiplicative factor $(1-\lambda)$ on the outside of your sum ).

The equivalent time series model ( in the sense that they give the same predictions ) is an arima(0,1,1). So, if you fit the arima(0,1,1)

$y_t - y_{t-1} = \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$

and get back the value of the estimated MA coefficient $\theta$, then you can use the mapping : $\hat{\lambda} = ( 1 - \hat{\theta})$. That will  give you the estimated value of $\lambda$.

Note that there's a proof somewhere that they are equivalent but it's been so long that I can't remember where you can find it. It might be in the Box-Jenkins-Reinsel text or in Harvey's structural time series text. Check Box-Jenkins-Reinsel first.

Note: The arima(0,1,1) is also equivalent to a random walk plus noise model so, if you're more familiar with the state space framework, you can fit that instead. See Harvey's text for details on that equivalence.

Comment: Your equation for ARIMA(0,1,1) is incorrect, and you do not explain how to estimate it.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I fixed the arima(0,1,1). As far as estimating it, I would use R and the arima function ( which does have some pitfalls ) but estimation really depends on the software one is using so I didn't feel the need to go into that discussion.  If the OP needs help with estimation, I assumed that he could just ask another question.

Comment: The OP's question seems to be specifically about estimation. Anyway, the ARIMA equation still seems to be incorrect. You wrote ARIMA(1,1,0) instead of ARIMA(0,1,1), did you not?

Comment: Oops. I'll fix it again. It's been so long since I looked at ARIMA model but that's no excuse. Thanks. As far as your second point, I took his question to be about how to re-write the exponential smoothing model so that it could be estimated. Hopefully, the OP will tell us whether I was correct ?